# Nested forEach activity in Azure Data factory V2

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to use two forEach activities to iterate on subfolders of folders with parameters to get metadata of subfolders. I have forEach1 and forEach2 with their own items array. Within the second for loop I need to combine both for loops' item() in a Metada activity to access my dataset like @item1()@item2(). Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Nested foreach activity is not allowed. But you could use an execute pipeline activity inside the foreach activity. And in the nested pipeline, you could have another foreach.

Comment: you can vote for nested foreach in adf there https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/b15882bd-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but the second ForEach activity needs to be inside the first one, not another activity in the pipeline.

As you have it now, the first ForEach will run until completion, then the second one will start and you cannot access the items in the first one.

Hope this helped!

Comment: forEach activity can't be placed inside another forEach, at least in the IU.

Comment: Mm I just checked and you are right, but the documentation doesn't say a thing about not nesting ForEach activities so I think it should work but you may not be able to create it with the UI. Another option would be to give the second forEach the parameters already concatenated with a lookup activity.

Comment: please vote for nested for each https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/b15882bd-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c